# Retrieving a value from a key in a json array

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I have a angularjs function which consist a json array as follows.

```
$scope.userDetails = [{
name: 'Anil Singh',
age: 30
 }, {
name: 'Reena Singh',
age: 25
}];
```

I need to get all the values of age key. Here is my code.

```
$scope.getAge = function()
{
    $scope.userDetails = [{
                     name: 'Anil Singh',
                     age: 30
                      }, {
                     name: 'Reena Singh',
                     age: 25
                     }];
    for(var i=0;i< $scope.userDetails.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("This is age"+$scope.userDetails[i].age);
    }
};
```

But when I check the console log it shows as the value is undefined.

Comment: is it throwing any error?

Comment: No error is thrown

Comment: first try printing out  the full `$scope.userDetails` array itself, like, `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.userDetails));` and show the result of it.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.getAge = function()
{
$scope.userDetails = [{
                     name: 'Anil Singh',
                     age: 30
                      }, {
                     name: 'Reena Singh',
                     age: 25
                     }];
for(var i=0;i< $scope.userDetails.length;i++)
{
     console.log("This is age"+$scope.userDetails[i].age);
}
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <button ng-click="getAge()">Get age</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I have the same code, when I inspect thr console log it doesn't show any value as expected. It shows  $scope.userDetails[i].age as undefined

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for all ages. please look in below code.

```js
var MyAppp = angular.module('MyAppp',[])
MyAppp.controller('ageController',function($scope){
$scope.getAge = function()
{
    $scope.userDetails = [{
                     name: 'Anil Singh',
                     age: 30
                      }, {
                     name: 'Reena Singh',
                     age: 25
                     }];
   var ages= $scope.userDetails.map(function(o){return o.age});
   console.log(ages)
   return ages;
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyAppp" ng-controller="ageController">
  <button ng-click="getAge()">Get age</button>
</div>
```